# Extract more frequent istances from list

Tags: r, list

I have a problem working with R list.

I have a large list of 113932 elements in which each of them represents a clique of people in a graph way. I want to find the more popular nodes and in terms of list. It means that I want to know how many times an instance is present in the elements of the list. Can anyone help me?

Here I paste an example of what I want to obtain:

```
list_n[[1]]
## [1] 149574 194554

list_n[[2]]
## [1] 149574 1245 1235 1255
```

The result of the function I would like to find or build should report the fact that 149574 is repeated twice.

Comment: `?unlist` / `?table` / `?sort`

Comment: `names(head(sort(table(unlist(list_n)), decreasing = TRUE), 1))`

Comment: yes sorry i don't explain very well my point. Operating in the way that you describe i can't know the clique (the element of the list) in which that particoular istance is present which is my point

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, i was not so clear, the function i would like to built was something like that

mia_f<-function(lis){

vett<-unlist(lis)

fd<-1:length(vett)

nm<-sapply(lis,length)

hg<-NULL

for (i in 1:length(nm))
   {

```
  f<-rep(i,nm[i])
  hg<-c(hg,f)
```

}

return(as.data.frame(rbind(vett,hg)) )

}

Answer (score 0):

Merge the list into a vector and then use table to get the frequency.

table(do.call(c, list_n))